# How does a group owner fork a project in gitlab?

Tags: gitlab

As a group owner in gitlab, i want to fork a project in the group namespace into my own user namespace. But when i open the project page in gitlab, i dont see the fork option on the page. How do I then fork the project ?

Comment: Fork option will be beside `star` option in Gitlab project page. Check for the owner permissions for the group again and refresh the page